# How to get top-level windows and their names using libxcb

Tags: c, xcb

I have a Linux desktop with 2 open windows: a terminal and a browser.  I'm trying to get the name of those windows with libxcb.  Here's my code based on examples I found at https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-xcb_query_tree_reply/

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

void get_children(xcb_connection_t* c, xcb_window_t window, xcb_window_t** children, int* count)
{
    *count = 0;
    *children = NULL;

    auto cookie = xcb_query_tree(c, window);
    auto reply = xcb_query_tree_reply(c, cookie, NULL);
    if (reply)
    {
        *count = xcb_query_tree_children_length(reply);
        *children = xcb_query_tree_children(reply);

        free(reply);
    }
}

void get_name(xcb_connection_t* c, xcb_window_t window, char** name, int* length)
{
    *length = 0;
    *name = NULL;

    auto cookie = xcb_get_property(c, 0, window, XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME, XCB_ATOM_STRING, 0, 0);
    auto reply = xcb_get_property_reply(c, cookie, NULL);
    if (reply)
    {
        *length = xcb_get_property_value_length(reply);
        *name = (char*)xcb_get_property_value(reply);

        free(reply);
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto c = xcb_connect(":0.0", NULL);
    auto screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(c)).data;
    auto rootWindow = screen->root;

    int nChildren;
    xcb_window_t* children;
    get_children(c, screen->root, &children, &nChildren);
    for (int i = 0; i < nChildren; i++)
    {
        auto wid = children[i];

        int length;
        char* name;
        get_name(c, wid, &name, &length);
        printf("%u %d\n", wid, length);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This returns 40 windows all with their name's length of 0.  For example:

```
20971989 0
20971802 0
20972112 0
20972308 0
... (truncated for brevity)
```

I'm trying to get something like the output of `wmctrl -l`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  I needed to add a length to the `xcb_get_property` function call.  The following code works.

```
auto cookie = xcb_get_property(c, 0, window, XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME, XCB_ATOM_STRING, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Good job sorting the issue out yourself. Point of style preference on your pointer declarations. When  you declare `char* a, b, c;` it does NOT declare 3 pointers to `char`, `char *a, b, c;` makes that clear. (declaration of one pointer to `char` and two character variables) In C, the `'*'` generally goes with the variable instead of the type. The compiler doesn't care -- it's a readability issue.

Comment: Also would make sure you compile with warnings enabled, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. You have a number to type problems with `int` and others in your code. `auto` isn't the cure-all it is being used as. The variable `rootWindow` is unused and can be deleted.